# Are comments across different pages of a website stored in one database table?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

How do websites like Facebook, Quora, Twitter store user comments? do they just have multiple tables filled with comment rows top to bottom? How do they retrieve replies? The way I would approach it is have a different table where replies can be indexed.

Comments Table

```
 commentID   User  Depth   Text               Date

   1          Greg    0     My name is greg    10/10/10
   2          Bill    1     My name is Bill    10/10/10
   3          Jeff    1     My name is jeff    10/10/10
```

Replies Table

```
commentID ReplyID
  1            2
  1            3
  2           EMPTY
  3           EMPTY
```

So if you were retrieving going to retrieve comments to serve up to a user you would begin with greg then index the replies table to find that comments 2 and 3 are replies then you index those replies and you see that there is no replies to those replies. I'm a noob at this and this is probably naive on my part but please tell me. And how would they store comments on a different page, I would just keep incrementing the IDs in the table of course there will be a BaseCommentID associated with each page that's associated with the ID of the first comment on the page so it knows which row to start reading comments from. And I assume in some cases there might even be a MAXDEPTH.

Enlighten me though, how do they do it?

Comment: Have a look at the tables used by stackoverflow perhaps? [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)  Do note that the utterly massive scale of things like Facebook may not apply in smaller scale problems.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Thanks!! that helped to clear a lot. Also I assume these pages are statically cached and upon user request the server just returns the cached html code. And when edits are made or new posts are created this cached html file is replaced with a new one. Is this correct?

Comment: That I cannot answer, but I too would assume there is caching in use

Comment: @funTertain Indeed your question is "how to model comment tree?" There are several methods fully described with examples in the section "Hierarchical data and trees in SQL" of the book ["Programming with databases"](https://www.amazon.com/dp/2956300806).